# Access the contents of an NSMutableArray between classes

Tags: iphone, ios, class, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` in one of my classes.  But I need to access the information contained within that array from another class.  I have tried using properties, but I eithor did it wrong, or its not working for me.  I tried `NSUserDefaults` but also no luck.  I tried using

`MainGame *mainGameClass = [[MainGame alloc]init];`

```
NSMutableArray *snacksLocationArray = main.snacksArray;
```

but none of this seems to work.
The two classes are named: `MainGame` and `Kool`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide access to your array then anyone should be able to access it. Using a `singleton` is more like making it a global variable than just allowing access to it.

```
// In MainGame.h
@interface MainGame : NSOBject {
    NSMutableArray *snacksLocationArray;
}
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *snacksLocationArray;
@end

// In MainGame.m
@implementation MainGame
@synthesize snacksLocationArray;
@end

// In Kool.h
@interface Kool : NSObject {
}
- (void) doSomethingFunkyWithSnacksArray: (NSMutatableArray *) a;
- (void) doSomethingWeirdWithMainGame: (MainGame *) g;
@end

// In Kool.m
@implementation Kool
- (void) doSomethingFunkyWithSnacksArray: (NSMutatableArray *) a {
    [a addObject: @"Funky"];
}
- (void) doSomethingWeirdWithMainGame: (MainGame *) g {
    [self doSomethingFunkyWithSnacksArray: g.snacksLocationArray];
    [g.snacksLocationArray addObject: @"Weird"];
}
```

Does this do what you are thinking? Lets you access the array from methods in `Kool`. "Funky" and "Weird" will be properly stored in the array for use within `MainGame`.

You could also set an ivar to the array within `Kool` for access to the array using methods that may not have access to the `MainGame` object.

Comment: `- (void) doSomethingWeirdWithMainGame: (MainGame *) g;` is returning an error for me

Answer (score 0):

You could use a singleton, on which you have your mutablearray set as a property. So you could call something like `[MainGame sharedGame].snacksArray` from anywhere within your app.

Here's what your `sharedGame` method should look like:

```
static MainGame *sharedGame = nil;

+ (MainGame *)sharedGame {

    if(sharedGame == nil)
        sharedGame = [[super alloc] init];

    return sharedGame;
}
```

Comment: well I don't understand any of this.  But thanks.  I put that method in MainGame, and then I called the array like you said from `Kool` like this NSMutableArray `*myArray = [MainGame sharedGame].snacksLocationArray;` and I get an error; snacksLocationArray is not a member of the structure or union.  What do you mean by set as a property.

Comment: Looks like you are missing some fundamental concepts of Objective-C programming, as properties is a pretty common concept. I'd recommend you burrow/buy some books that will help get you further into it. Maybe go through this great tutorial by Mike Rundle: http://designthencode.com/scratch/